# How to disambiguate binary versus unary operators in expression evaluation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Take the following expression:

$$
2 \color{red}+ 3x \color{orange}- 4y
$$

By convention, unary plus signs ($+$) are omitted in notation. If we explicitly include them, we have:

$$
+2 \color{red}+ (+3x) \color{orange}- 4y
$$

This makes it clear that the original $\color{red}+$ symbol was a binary addition operator. My question is: **how do we disambiguate whether the $\color{orange}-$ operator is unary or binary between the 2nd and 3rd terms?**

To maintain consistency with the above, we would have the following:

$$
+2 \color{red}+ (+3x) \color{orange}- (+4y)
$$

Where the $\color{orange}-$ operator is binary. However, in textbooks, typically the $\color{orange}-$ operator is said to be "attached" to the following term, which would make it an unary operator and give us either:

$$
+2 \color{red}+ (+3x) \color{green}+ (\color{orange}-4y)
$$

or

$$
+2 \color{red}+ (+3x) \color{green}- (\color{orange}-4y)
$$

If this latter scenario is correct: **how do we know which sign the binary operator should be between the 2nd and 3rd terms if it is not explicitly provided, as in the first expression?**

Comment: The convention is that $a-b = a+(-b)$.

Comment: "$2+3x-4y$" is not ambigious. Even if we start with $3x-4y$ and add $2$ , we get the correct result. I see no other possible interpretation.

Comment: A problem occurs if we write $a-b-c$ without parantheses. This should be avoided although the usual intepretation would be "$(a-b)-c$"

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you, this was what I had gleaned from looking at textbooks. So essentially this means that terms in a polynomial are _always_ added together unless there are two explicit minus operators between terms, like: $2 + 3x - (-4y)$. If only a single operator is present, terms are always added together.

Comment: The dropping of parentheses is a notational convenience which comes along with some conventions (like PEMDOS). 'Ideally' all expressions would be fully parenthesised so that there would be no ambiguities.

Comment: Peter, It is ambiguous if you do not know what the underlying convention is. As @copper.hat has clarified, it seems that, by convention, unary positive symbols are omitted when a binary addition symbol is present between terms, while binary addition symbols are omitted when a negative unary symbol is present on the following term. So the following expression $+2 + (+3x) + (-4y)$ is by convention presented as $2 +3x -4y$.

Comment: @Stropharia Then , tell me how "$2+3x-4y$" can be misinterpreted (my comment was only about this particular expression).

Comment: @Peter If you don't know the conventions, then it could be interpreted as either $2+(+3)+(-4)$, $2+(+3)−(+4)$, or $2+(+3)−(-4)$. The first two of these will ultimately evaluate to the same result, while the third will not.

Comment: @Peter Also, only the second expression maintains consistency for both the positive and negative operators - i.e., because the unary plus operator is omitted between both sets of terms. The first expression, which is by convention correct, uses different rules for the positive versus negative operators - between the first two terms, the binary operator is shown and the unary operator omitted, while between the last two terms the unary operator is shown and the binary operator omitted. The different rules seem to relate to the sign of the term. This is what I found confusing.

Comment: "$2+(+3x)-(-4y)$" is not a reasonable interpretation of "$2+3x-4y$" , it makes no sense to assume that $-(-4y)$ , which is $+4y$ , is meant. I cannot follow what confused you here.

Comment: @Peter It makes sense to me now, having thought about it more, that that would be an unreasonable interpretation. A friend of mine said that the easiest way to think about operations with polynomials is that all terms are always added to one another, but each term can have a coefficient that is either positive or negative. So, thinking about an expression like this $(+7y^2) + (+9x) + (-2z) + (-5)$ but writing it like this $7y^2 + 9x - 2z - 5$. This makes sense to me.